# Prediction intervals for HTS forecasting

Tags: r, confidence-interval, prediction-interval, multilevel-analysis

So I have a lot of time series with a hierarchical structure, and need to produce forecast for each base series and its aggregates by  the hierarchical structure.

I have decided to produce forecast using the R hts package by Rob J Hyndman. I have produced reasonable point forecast for each series using the auto.arima function, and the forecast.gts function as in [hts-viggnete](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/vignettes/hts.pdf) page9. But prediction intervals are not yet implented directly in the package so I have followed the formulations in [ref1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.445.2341&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to get the variance matrix sigma.

But now Im lost in how to produce prediction intervals, should I use the diagonal of this matrix as the variance of each series to produce naive intervals? as in:

```
    c(-1,1)*diag(sigma)+aggts(myhts.forecast)
```

Is using the combinef() function on the intervals given by the auto.arima a correct way to produce conficence intervals?

thank you.